# Getting "Access Denied" on "Invoke-PnpQuery"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, pnp-powershell

I am trying to move a site in SharePoint Online but get an error while doing so. Code :

````
*$NewSiteURL = "/sites/Helix/HelixArchive/TobeArchived"*

*Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $usercredential*

*$Web = Get-PnPWeb*

*$Web.ServerRelativeUrl = $NewSiteURL*

*$Web.Update()*

*Invoke-PnPQuery*```

Error :

*Invoke-PnPQuery : Access denied.
At C:\Users\Userid\Documents\Untitled6.ps1:15 char:1
+ Invoke-PnPQuery
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-PnPQuery], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException,SharePointPnP. 
   PowerShell.Commands.Base.InvokeQuery*

I am a Global Administrator and has full control on the sites in question.
1 thing i found is that i do not get any error when the url is like
https://domain.sharepoint.com/**development**/cloudsite/helix" {Any string instead of **sites**}, I am able to move the site successfully then.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.
````

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. Set DenyAndAddCustomizePages to false, run the code and if required, set it to true again.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens that, when you create the Modern Site, it takes a while to configure all the security settings.

Comment: Thanks for your comments but i am getting this error on old sites also which has been there for months. I don't think that it has anything to do with delay in configuring all the security settings